# Php script for name verification + password for authorization / registration

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

This php script checks the existence of the name and password in the json file.If the user does not exist with the same name, we add it to our json file. If it exists, check the password with the previously saved password. If the passwords do not match, tell the user about it.Please help fix.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var name = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'php/login_script.php',
      data: {
        user: name,
        pass: password
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="register">
  <form method="POST" id="form">
    <p>Enter your name</p>

    <input type="text" name="username" id="username">

    <p>Enter your pasword</p>

    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </form>
</div>
<input type="Submit" id="submit">
```

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

if (isset($name) && isset($password)) {
    $file = 'users.json';
$new_name = array('Name' => $name, 'Password' => $password);
$new_name = json_encode($new_name, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, FILE_APPEND);

file_put_contents($file, $new_name );
$fileq = file_get_contents('users.json');         

$taskList = json_decode($fileq,TRUE);

if (in_array($name, $taskList)) {
    echo "Name is busy";

}
else{
    echo "name is empty";

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Write first what happens not as expected.

Comment: @Zydnar When there is a check of presence of the password in a file, always leaves "This name is busy"

Comment: I haven't seen the structure of your json but it is strange to put all passwords and user names in one array. What if two different users have same password? And why check at all if some of them use this password? I think there should be only one "if".

Comment: @Zydnar  If two different users have same password its fine, if username are diff.So, i  should make one array for `$name` and one more for `$password`?

Comment: First try change line with $content to: $data = file_get_contents($filename); $content = $data ?json_decode($data, true) : 
    ['Name' => $name, 'Password' => $password];

Comment: @Zydnar Error-"file_get_contents(data/users.json):failed to open stream.No such file or directory in" But this file in this directory.

Comment: Maybe insufficient permissions, typo or wrong paths in this environment eg. in Linux './folder', '/folder' are not the same.

Comment: @Zydnar I checked everything and the paths are correct. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know or I am missing something.